# How to serialize self-defined objects in Groovy

Tags: groovy

This code...

```
class A implements Serializable{
  String str
  int n
}

try{
  def a= new A(str:'abc', n:7)
  def out= new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream('serializedObject.obj'))
  out.writeObject(a)
  out.close()
}finally{}

try{
  def inp= new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream('serializedObject.obj'))
  def a2= inp.readObject()
  inp.close()
}finally{}
```

...produces error...

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: A
    at java_io_ObjectInput$readObject.call(Unknown Source)
    at otherRun.run(otherRun.groovy:16)
```

...when attempting to reload the object in the 2nd try block. It works OK when the class is a predefined class such as java.util.List. The **above code also works OK when converted line-for-line into Java**.

How can I get it working in Groovy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put your "class A" into its own file and make sure the "A.class" file is availbale (in classpath) where you read the object.

Comment: I guessed that would work without trying it out, and in fact that's my ultimate goal for using serialization in Groovy. It's very convenient, however, to experiment with new Java/Groovy features using a single source file in Groovy, before formalizing it with multiple files, packages, performance enhancements, etc. Because **the code works OK when converted line-for-line into Java**, perhaps Groovy should also enable it.

Comment: If you have a singel source file and execute it, the "class A" might be compiled several times ... usually getting a wiered name. This also can lead to strange behaviour.